# How to automatically forward mail with Postfix/Dovecot?

Tags: mysql, email, postfix, dovecot, linode

I set up Postfix/Dovecot with MySQL on a Linode instance from [this tutorial](http://library.linode.com/email/postfix/dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-10.04-lucid), and I am now trying to forward all email that comes to someaddress@mydomain.com to anotheraddress@anotherdomain.com automatically. For some reason, even after extensive Googling I can't find a guide on how to do that with that particular setup. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 8):

You have to certify that you have an `alias_map` or `alias_database` entry in your `main.cf`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

then, inside that file set you alias as desired:

```
someaddress:    anotheraddress@anotherdomain.com
```

after that run `newaliases` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to work. Since I have Postfix set up with MySQL, aren't aliases set up through there? Nothing I changed in /etc/aliases seemed to work, even after restarting the Postfix service.

Comment: Can you post your `postconf -n`? Have you tried with `alias_map`?

Comment: Here's my postconf -n: http://pastebin.com/a4VJ2PWR
I tried with both `alias_database` and `alias_maps`

Comment: Have you checked the file `mysql-virtual_email2email.cf` and the table associated with it?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a bit late, but here's one really pleasant post on how to set mail forwarding with Postfix/Dovecot through the `virtual_alias_map` parameter:

https://geekpeek.net/configure-postfix-mail-forward/

where this article is tightly related to another one by the same author, which can be found [here](https://geekpeek.net/postfix-with-dovecot/). I recommend checking them out both, because they refer each other too much anyway.

So it seems that the right way to do forwarding it through the *virtual alias class* and the `virtual_alias_map` parameter.

Full documentation on the *virtual alias class* can be found in the Postfix's docs reference [here](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html#virtual_alias_class) and [here](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html), and an example [here](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding).

So here's what Postfix say:

> #### The virtual alias domain class.
>
> Purpose: *hosted domains* where each recipient address is aliased to a *local* UNIX system account or to a *remote address*.

And finally the mail forwarding example:

> ### Mail forwarding domains
>
> Some providers host domains that have no (or only a few) local
>   mailboxes. The main purpose of these domains is to forward mail
>   elsewhere. The following example shows how to set up example.com as a
>   mail forwarding domain:
>
> ```
>  1 /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>  2     virtual_alias_domains = example.com ...other hosted domains...
>  3     virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
>  4 
>  5 /etc/postfix/virtual:
>  6     postmaster@example.com postmaster
>  7     joe@example.com        joe@somewhere
>  8     jane@example.com       jane@somewhere-else
>  9     # Uncomment entry below to implement a catch-all address
> 10     # @example.com         jim@yet-another-site
> 11     ...virtual aliases for more domains...
> ```

Source: http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite the from address? I have this working perfectly, but when I forward emails that came from another domain to be forwarded to an email outside of my domain, the SMTP server I am using to relay does not allow me to forward emails that did not originate from my domain.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if you have "virtual mailboxes" already setup and want to use forwarding in addition to them:

https://superuser.com/questions/721917/mixing-virtual-forwards-and-virtual-mailboxes-in-postfix